# Draw direction offline on image map

Tags: android, jquery, asp.net, dictionary

I have jpg image of a mall map, and I want to make an application which will take the destination and show the static direction to shop inside the mall and no need for showing current location.

How can I draw directions on the map and how can I define the shops area and the route to fill?

Anything will help in Java Android, C# or in jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: I require the same kind of functionality but for iOS purpose.

Comment: if using jQuery might suggest overlaying transparent png files over the map. each png might contain the different routes/annotations and you can alternate between them as required?